# Music setting of iOS APP

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question about iOS system and iOS app.

When I playing iPhone’s music, some app will stop the music when I open it.

For example: Line Ranger.
Some app will let the music

playing continuously, like Facebook.

If I made an app, how do I set the settings?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS how to don't stop music when the app start launching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762544/ios-how-to-dont-stop-music-when-the-app-start-launching)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Now I am studying the relative code.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the category you want to AVAudioSession you are using.

```
/* set session category */  
- (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category error:(NSError **)outError;
```

Available categories are:

```
#pragma mark -- Values for the category property --  

/*  Use this category for background sounds such as rain, car engine noise, etc. Mixes with other music. */  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient;  

/*  Use this category for background sounds.  Other music will stop playing. */  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient;  

/* Use this category for music tracks.*/  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback;  

/*  Use this category when recording audio. */  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord;  

/*  Use this category when recording and playing back audio. */  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord;  

/*  Use this category when using a hardware codec or signal processor while not playing or recording audio. */  
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing;
```